# What's wrong with the positioning in this very simple example? (MS IE 8)

Tags: css

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="panel" id="Panel1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 136px; width: 136px; height: 48px;">
<legend> </legend>
  <div class="label" id="Label1" style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 16px; width: 81px; height: 14px;">panel one</div>
</fieldset>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="Panel2">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 272px; width: 185px; height: 64px;">
<legend> </legend>
  <div class="Label" id="Label3" style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 64px; width: 64px; height: 14px;">panel two</div>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
body {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
}

.panel, Label, .fieldset {
  font: 8px Arial; 
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Panel one has `left=136px` and `width=136px` while panel two has `left=372px` but when I look at them in MS IE 8 they overlap. What gives?

---

A few points of info

- Obviously, I am a relative CSS newbie.
- This is part of a project to design a form in a Windows program and then view it in the browser. It has to be WYSIWYG, which is why I am giving precise coordinates, rather than allowing the browser to lay out the page.
- But might it be that I would be better off with `style="position: fixed;` ?
- I am not sure if I need positioning on both the `div`s and their contents, but, if only one, then which?
- I made the example as simple as possible, but it must scale up to multiply nested fieldsets

  - I have no choice but to use MS IE, although I can recommend a (minumum) version.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: your second fieldset is not closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect. The style definitions that are on your `fieldset` element, should be on your `div` elements for panel 1 and 2. Also your `fieldset` tag in panel2 is unclosed.

Try this HTML:

```
<div class="panel" id="Panel1" style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 136px; width: 136px; height: 48px;">
    <fieldset >
        <legend> </legend>
        <div class="label" id="Label1" style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 16px; width: 81px; height: 14px;">panel one</div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="Panel2" style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 272px; width: 185px; height: 64px;">
    <fieldset >
        <legend> </legend>
        <div class="Label" id="Label3" style="position: absolute; top:8px; left: 64px; width: 64px; height: 14px;">panel two</div>
    </fieldset>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you try this in MS IE 8?   The panels are suddenly only a few pixels high (maybe 8?) with the text below them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have IE8 here at work. Try putting `overflow:auto;` in their style as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Strelok pointed out, there are mistakes in your HTML. I also notice that your css refers to elements with a class of fieldset did you want that to be on the fieldset itself?

if so, in the css remove the `.` before `.fieldset`

Comment: Btw, shoudl the styling be on the enclosing div or the fieldset? Should there even be an enslosing div? It's only there for the sytle.

Comment: If you don't need the div to group elements not already grouped by the fieldset, you shouldn't need to use that enslosing div.

Answer (score 0):

try putting relative on the surrounding div.
`.panel{posistion:relative}`

Comment: I'll try, but it sounds like you want me to leave the style on the fieldset, whereas @Strelok wants me to move it to the div. No wonder i am confsued :-)

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit? Your answer is incorrectly formatted (using the `pre` tag doesn't get you code highlighting) and you spelled `position` wrong.